# Five Card Flush on the table

Tags: texas-hold-em

Is it an automatic split between two players, if there is an ace high flush on the table and one player has no hearts in his hand ?

Comment: Thank you all for the information..so I'm understanding that with the five card flush on the table, if neither of the two players in the pot have a card of the same suit, no question, automatic split..but if one player has a card of the flush suit higher than the lowest card on the table (or any other), if the other player has no card of the suit, then the pot goes to the player with any card of the flush suit?

Answer (score 1):

When there are 5 Cards of one suit on the board it will be a split in case no other player has a card of that suit which is higher than the lowest card of the suit on the board.

If the board shows already a straight flush, you wont win even if you hold the ace of that suit. in case you wont make the royal flush using that ace...

Since all cards of the same suit, there is no full house possible.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 5 card flush on the table, it will be a split unless some players are able to provide some combination of 5 cards that is a full house, straight flush, 4 of a kind, etc that is better than flush

Comment: How to make a full house using a board of 5 different cards?